# Ruflin/Elastica + ES6 thorws error: Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported

Tags: php, elasticsearch, header, elastica

Can somebody help me please fix the problem with headers send from Ruflin/Elastica to Elasticsearch 6. It seems Ruflin/Elastica is old version which is not quite compatible with Elasticsearch 6. As I found out [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests) Elasticsearch changes its behavior related to request headers as doc says: Starting from Elasticsearch 6.0, all REST requests that include a body must also provide the correct content-type for that body.

I can not change the version of Ruflin/Elastica library so I would like to fix the content type header but don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me please?
The code looks like:

```
$query = sprintf('{
            "size": %s,
            "_source": %s,
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "ico": %s
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }', $this->limit, json_encode($cols), json_encode($icos));

$elastica = new Elastica\Client(["host" => 'localhost']);

$resp = $elastica->request('search_4/_search', Elastica\Request::POST, json_decode($query, TRUE))->getData();
```